# ggplot2 - geom_point with pattern fill of shapes does not change even though I change the colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, geom-point

I have been struggling since yesterday with this issue. I am trying to make the following geom_point figure with a black border for the points and two different colors, one per condition grey for the LF-EB and white for the HF-EB. However, even though I used other suggestions from different posts, the color does not change using scale_fill_manual() or scale_color_manual(). Any suggestions?

Here is the code:

```
ggplot(RQ.Di, aes(x = rounded_time, y = avg_RQ, color=condition, shape = interaction(condition,group), group = interaction(group, condition))) +
  geom_line(color = "black") +
  geom_point(size = 2.5, color="black", stroke=1) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(24, 24, 22, 22, 23, 23)) + #https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2075 to find the shapes code
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("black", "grey","black", "grey","black", "grey")) +
  labs(x = "Time", y = "RQ") +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "1 hour", date_labels = "%H:%M", minor_breaks = NULL) +
  theme(
    text = element_text(family = "Palatino Linotype"),
    axis.text = element_text(size = 12, color = "black"),
    axis.title = element_text(size = 12, color = "black", face = "bold"),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 12, color = "black", face = "bold"),
    panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", fill = NA, size = 1),
    legend.key = element_rect(fill = "transparent")
  )
```

-UPDATE
I modified it by using fill instead of color =  interaction(group, condition). However, now that I am seeing the legend does not match to what I have with other figures. I would like the legend to divide the group and condition by ; instead of .

I tried to change the using the scale_fill_discrete and changing the labels. However, this will duplicate the legend and disappear the color/shape legend that you see in the following picture:
[image]

Comment: Use `fill = condition` not `color = condition` inside `aes()`. And if `condition` has two unique values, `LF-EB` and `HF-EB`, your `scale_fill_manual` should also only have 2 unique values.

Comment: (And a side-note, you can find the shapes at the `?pch` help page if you scroll down a little bit)

Comment: Thank you!! 

However, now my legend does not represent the shape and fillings rather, I have a double legend, one for condition and another one for interaction.

Comment: And see [the ggplot2-specs vignette for shapes](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-specs.html#point).

Comment: I add to fill=interaction, so it disappear the duplicated legend

Comment: If you could provide some example data, we can help you more easily.

Comment: The easiest and friendliest way to share sample data is with `dput()`, e.g., `dput(RQ.Di[1:20, ])` for the first 20 rows of your data. `dput()` will give copy/pasteable R code to replicate your data including all class and structure information.

Comment: This is the solution I found: I added to fill=interaction, so it disappears the duplicated legend – 


Now I am dealing with how to change the names of the legend since it describes an interaction. I tried different options with the scale_fill_discrete option. I can remove the legend title within theme(). But not the names, as I want them to match other figures I created earlier.

Comment: The code, is way to long for the comment. What I can do is update the post.